# Evitar que teclado oculte vistas, ¿Como usar windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"?

Tags: android, android-layout

tengo un layout para una actividad en el cual cuando voy a utilizar el teclado android este oculta algunos views, he estado buscando y me dicen que para solucionarlo habría que utilizar el siguiente atributo: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`.

Lo he probado a poner en el manifest dentro de la actividad y en este layout en el RelativeLayout que contiene todos los demas Views pero sigue sin funcionar, ¿Cómo tendría que utilizarlo?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="Insertar"
android:id="@+id/rl"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/view2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/formularioUd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <!--android:layout_below="@id/toolbarInsertarUD"-->

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/universal_margin"
        android:textColorHint="#5ca0d1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etNombre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#000"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/universal_margin"
        android:textColorHint="#5ca0d1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etDescripcion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btGuardar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="alClickearBoton"
    android:text="@string/insert"
    android:layout_below="@+id/formularioUd"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cross"
    android:background="#5ca0d1"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El atributo que indicas en realidad es una referencia a un tema y no es una solución:

```
android:theme="@style/PLMS_Style"
```

Para asegurar el teclado virtual no cubra el widget al activarlo, se agrega la propiedad

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"
```

O

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Estoy gilipollas xDD es que no quería poner eso, quise poner `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` pero pegué otra cosa  -.-'' . Gracias de todas maneras !

Comment: Hehe un saludo @borjis

Answer (score 1):

Vale, ya he encontrado la solución, utilizando `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` en la actividad de declarada en el manifiesto funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Buen trabajo! :)